# Reconnect to server after losing connection with Tcp Socket

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcpclient

I tried to use dont linger to reconnect to the server when losing connection

```
Public Class Agent
    Dim bytes(1024) As Byte
    Dim remoteEP As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(My.Settings("HostIP").ToString), CType(My.Settings("HostPort"), Integer))
    Dim permis As New SocketPermission(NetworkAccess.Connect, TransportType.Tcp, "", SocketPermission.AllPorts)
    Dim S As New Net.Sockets.Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
```

If connect is successful it goeos to `getdatadb`, if not it goes to `socketclose` first and then it tries to connect again

```
   Sub Connect()
        Try
            S.Connect(remoteEP)
        Catch ex As Exception
            socketclose()
            S.Connect(remoteEP)
        End Try
        GetDataDb()
    End Sub
```

with this to close the socket

```
   Sub socketclose()
        Dim myOpts As New LingerOption(True, 1)
        S.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Linger, myOpts)
        S.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.DontLinger, False)
        S.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both)
        S.Close()


    End Sub
```

but it still shows exception

> Once the socket has been disconnected, you can only reconnect again
>   asynchronously, and only to a different EndPoint.  BeginConnect must
>   be called on a thread that won't exit until the operation has been
>   completed.

I don't know why dontlinger doesn't work.